# Question on the proof of existence of splitting fields for a family of polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

I have a question regarding the following well known result: Let $C\subseteq K[x]$ be a family of polynomials. We know that $C$ possesses a splitting field over $K$. The proof I am reading goes like this:

Let $(f_i)_{i\in I}$ be a well ordering of $C$. Since we know how to form the splitting field of a single polynomial, we can define the splitting field inductively as, $K_i$:= splitting field of $f_i$ over $\bigcup_{j<i} K_j$ and $L:=\bigcup_{i\in I}K_i$.

Question: I do not understand how $K_i$ is defined inductively. I mean how do we form the union $\bigcup_{j<i} K_j$ to start with?

Edit: if the family is finite or countable then I can understand this proof, but not otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

As side-effect of the construction will be that $K_j\subseteq K_i$ whenever $j<i$. Since the $K_j$ are sets, we can certainly talk about their union $\bigcup_{j<i}K_j$. To show that this set-union is a field, note that for $a,b\in \bigcup_{j<i}K_j$ there exist $j_1, j_2$ with $a\in K_{j_1}$ and $b\in K_{j_2}$. Then $a,b\in K_j$ with $j=\max\{j_1,j_2\}<i$ and in $K_j$ both $a+b$ and $a\cdot b$ are defined - and will give the same result also for any other $j'$ with $a,b\in K_{j'}$! Thus $\bigcup_{j<i}K_j$ carries operations $+$ and $\cdot$ and these make it a field (by similar find-a-common-$j$-arguments).

Comment: But how the $K_j$ is formed with $j<i$?. How will we start? I mean we dont necessarily have a minimal element. There is something very trivial that I must not be seeing. But thanks for the explanation, it has made things a little bit more clear except this minor thing.